# cordova android sql select returning length 1 but no rows

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I'm having some weird behaviour on this app I'm developing. While testing on browser everything seems to work fine, but I tried deploying my app on a device to test and apparently everything `WebSQL` related works fine up until I do a select. My `SQLResultSet` is returning *length = 1* on the rows but there are no rows there. I tried to inspect the app and look at the Resources tab on chrome and the `database` IS created and there is actually one row there. So it is returning the right length but not the rows.

Anyone had anything like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was supposed to use the `result.rows.item(idx)` method on the result rows but I was fetching the rows directly through `result.rows[idx]`. Apparently this is supported by Chrome's implementation but is not standard. Using `result.rows.item(idx)` fixed it.